# is there efficient library for QR CODE or Barcode, not zxing

Tags: android

is there any other efficient and fast library for scanning barcode or qr code... i have used zxing but it is failed in scanning for most of SAMSUNG GALAXY PHone..... i have also used this library but i also facing same problem....

I have find-out most review about zxing most of galaxy phone's user have to face problem of scanning which is below i find our from google play store

```
 Kevin - September 26, 2012 - Samsung Galaxy S2 with version 4.3
 Brad Will not focus on bar codes using my Galaxy SII.

 ivan - September 26, 2012 - Samsung Galaxy S2 with version 4.3
 Auto blurs
 Auto focus is now auto blur. I thought it was my camera or some gunk on my lens, but     no, quick clean and test with regular camera app confirms that it's the app that's broken.

 Nuky - September 25, 2012 - Samsung Galaxy S2 with version 4.3
 Don't work it anymore after the update


 nups - July 12, 2012 - HTC One X with version 4.2
 Does not recognise a lot of barcodes...
 The app does not recognize a lot of barcodes that it should since they belong to      books..hope they fix this...

 Emily Sara Taylor - July 20, 2012 - Version 4.2
 Never works on Galaxy Q
 I don't know if it's because of the phone or what but this app has never worked on any bar code I've tried. Won't focus on it at all.

 Aidan - July 12, 2012 - Samsung Galaxy Y with version 4.2
 Does not do all
 This is a good app but it does not scan normal barcodes only the ones that are     desinged for smart phones but would be 5starts if they fig this
```

this are all the review of https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out [zbar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/), there is a sample in the SDK, quite easy to integrate into your app.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try out the [Scandit barcode scanner SDK](http://www.scandit.com) for Android. It also works with low-end Android phones that only have a fixed focus camera with a low resolution and it is pretty straightforward to integrate.

Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=qozc_3iLAfQ) showing the barcode scanning performance on a two-year old HTC device.

The Scandit SDK comes with a free community version and there is also a product API that translates UPCs to product names.

(Disclaimer: I am a co-founder of Scandit)